# CSS positioning, overlaying divs in fluid layout

Tags: css, fluid-layout, css-position

It's my first time designing a fluid layout and one of the things I'm trying to do is overlay a caption at the bottom of a photo. The method I'm using is having the photo (width:100%) inside a div (width:50%) and adding a div containing the caption under the photo. To get it to overlay, I made the caption's height a static 30px and set the position as relative and top -50px (+padding).

**CSS:**

```
#contentdiv {
    width:50%;
}
#gallerydescription {
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
    background-image:url(../contentbkg.png);
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contentdiv">
   <img src="blog/1.gif" width="100%" />
   <div id="gallerydescription">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dictum urna nec urna varius varius.
   </div>
</div>
```

This does what I want visually, but it's not really a true fluid layout and it looks ugly if the caption is too or too short. Is there a way where I could let the length of the caption to determine the height of the caption div and have the "top" be the negative of whatever the height and padding is?

Comment: You would need to use jquery to work out that type of maths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure CSS solution for a problem *like* the one you have

### CSS

```
      #contentdiv{
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
     }
     #gallerydescription{
        padding: 10px;
        background-image: url('../contentbkg.png');
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 60%;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
```

### Markup (unchanged)

```
 <div id="contentdiv">
     <img src="blog/1.gif" width="100%" />
     <div id="gallerydescription">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dictum urna nec urna varius varius.
     </div>
  </div>
```

### Update

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz5R4/) try this fiddle

Comment: This would not work if you make `width: 100%;` and add also `padding: 10px;` because total width would be bigger than 100% and make scroll bar appear :). Padding should be added inside another element

Comment: which element's width you're talking about? I'm certain that you've not read the CSS part closely nor you've tried the fiddle ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see how it looks like:

```
#contentdiv {
    width:50%;
    position: relative
}
#gallerydescription {
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
    background-image:url(../contentbkg.png);
    position:absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: so you didn't read `but it's not really a true fluid layout and it looks ugly if the caption is too or too short. Is there a way where I could let the length of the caption to determine the height of the caption div` while adding `height: 30px` to `#gallerydescription`

Answer (score -1):

You could try [jQuery UI Position](http://jqueryui.com/position/) for that purpose.

It allows to position two elements relatively, like

```
$("#elementToPosition").position({
  my: "left top",
  at: "right bottom",
  of: "#targetElement"
});
```

And then change the top property for overlaying :

```
$("#elementToPosition").css('top',$("#elementToPosition").css('top') - 10px);
```